# How to include and install local dependencies in setup.py in Python?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am creating a **setup.py** to distribute my application.
This application has a number of dependencies which can be installed via pip, it also has some custom dependencies which can not be installed from PyPI.

So, I have created a `custom_package_0.1.whl` which will be included into the distribution and must be installed as a dependency after **setup.py** installs everything from `install_requires`.

Imagine the following app structure:

```
my_app/
    win_deps/custom_package_0.1.whl
    my_app/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        setup.py
        setup.cfg
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I had a similar problem and found a satisfying answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059111/build-a-wheel-egg-and-all-dependencies-for-a-python-project)

Comment: It's a shame for such widely known language to not support local dependencies in a non hacky way...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it is possible but not sure what setuptools version you should use.
steps:

in setup.py

```
setup(
  ...,
  install_requires=['my-package'],
  dependency_links=[
    # location to your egg file
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'deps', 'my_package-1.0.0-py3.5.egg')
  ]
)
```

important thing is that your location should not pass URL pattern test and egg file name should have structure `<package_name_with_no_hyphens>-<version>-<py_version>.egg`

Comment: It seems like this wouldn't work if you haven't already installed `my-package` because there is no .egg until you install it, right?

Comment: @medley56 I don't think that you need to install `my-package` with conda or something different. setuptools reads it from local location I guess

Comment: [dependency_links has been removed](https://github.com/Applied-GeoSolutions/gips/issues/246)

Comment: this does not work for newer pip versions, scroll to my answer for something that works with pip >= 19.1

Answer (score 32):

There is a new technique (Since version 19.1) called [Direct references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references).
Just pretend like your file is hosted on localhost.

```py
from setuptools import setup

path_to_my_project = "/home/user/projects/my_package"  # Do any sort of fancy resolving of the path here if you need to


setup(# ... other arguments
      install_requires=[f"my_package @ file://localhost/{path_to_my_project}#egg=my_package"]
      )
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with Python 3.10 and setuptools 59. I get the error message `Couldn't find index page for <package>' (maybe misspelled?)` with either `localhost` or `localbuilds` specified.

Comment: Nothing in the [release history](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html) suggests that something changed here

Comment: Yeah, I think that this is an issue in setuptools, rather than pip. I stumbed over this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650046/pip-use-project-folder-as-installation-source

Answer (score 5):

Based on @RunOrVeith answer above this works for a local wheel file using a relative path.  So it can be used on various hosts to install a third party package.  Works on Windows and Unix.

```
setup(# ... other arguments
      install_requires=[
          f"my-lib @ file://localhost/{os.getcwd()}/libs/my_lib-xxx-none-any.whl"
      ]
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that if depending on 'cwd' is the correct way, what if cwd changes ?

Comment: Since the ".../libs" is relative to the setup.py seems ok to me.  If you move the entire project to another folder run "pip install -e ." and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Extending wiesiu_p's answer, you can install the dependency by linking to its source directory, which has its own `setup.py`.

Assume you have the source files of your dependency `my-dependency`, and the root of `my-dependency` has its own `setup.py`. In your application's `setup.py`:

```
setup(
  ...,
  install_requires=['other-dependency','my-dependency'],
  dependency_links=[
    # location to your my-dependency project directory
    ''.join(['file:\\', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'path', 'to', 'my-dependency#egg=my-dependency-1.0')])
  ]
)
```

Now if you run `python setup.py install` with your application's `setup.py`, it will install `my-dependency`.

Comment: I know this comment is old but I cannot get it to work.  I tried with both `files:\\` as you have it and `files://` which I think is correct? doing `pip install --find-links=<dep_link> my_package` works, but not when I put it in setup.py

Comment: I've added some clarification to the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Note that this might fail if the local dependency itself has local dependencies, because the getcwd() might be called from site-packages.

Comment: This does not work for me: it says that `ERROR: No matching distribution found for my-dependency` when I do `pip install -e .`. Even if I do `python setup.py install` I get an error `error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('my-dependency')`. I'm using pip 20.3.3.

Comment: See my answer for how to get this to work with newer pip versions

Comment: Should that be `file://` instead of `file:\\ `?

Comment: @Sören Pretty sure it's ```file:\\```. Did that not work for you?

Comment: I've never seen an URI written that way, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me when installing a local namespace package.

This is my directory structure:

```
mynamespace_project
├───namespace-package-a
│   ├───setup.py
│   └───namespace
│       └───a
│           ├───__init__.py
│           └───foo.py
└───namespace-package-b
    ├───setup.py
    └───namespace
        └───b
            ├───__init__.py
            └───bar.py
```

Then to require `namespace-package-a` in `namespace-package-b`, `b` would have the following `setup.py`:

```py
setup(
      # ... other arguments
      install_requires=[
          f"package-a @ {(Path(__file__).parent.parent/"namespace-package-a").as_uri()}"
      ]
)
```

Running `pip install namespace-package-b` will then correctly install namespace-package-a with b.

Then in your code, you can import under the common namespace like so:

```py
from namespace.a import foo
from namespace.b import bar
```

Answer (score -4):

There are several options that you can choose from:

1. Upload your package to some server, and provide the URL with `dependency_links`.
2. You could put your python package inside of your `my_app` package and link it with `packages` parameter, instead of using the wheel file.
3. A more hacky way would be to use the `setuptools` api, and install the package by yourself.

Comment: For `2`, how should I do that? I moved "win_deps" into "my_app" and added `packages=(['win_deps'])` but running `python2 setup.py install` does not automatically install all the `.whl` packages from "win_deps" directory

Comment: What I meant in 2 was that instead of supplying the `whl` package, you could move the entire package directory `custom_package_0.1` into this package directory.

Comment: oh, you mean just move `custom_package_0.1` source files into `win_deps`?

Comment: exactly. The problem is that setup.py does not have any available option to install a wheel package. The only way I can see is what I suggested you to do. The other ways are more hacky ways and I would not recommend you to do so.

Comment: Can you add more info for the third? Thanks.

Comment: this is a terrible accepted answer. it has no details on the solutions