# How do I handle namespace packages that will serve as dependencies for another package

Tags: python, namespaces, package, setuptools

I have written three Python modules, two of them are independent but the last one would depend on the two independent modules. For example, consider the following structure

```
myProject/
    subpackage_a/
        __init__.py
        ...
    subpackage_b/
        __init__.py
        ...
    mainpackage/
        __init__.py
        ...
```

`mainpackage` depends on `subpackage_a` and `subpackage_b`, where as `subpackage_a` and `subpackage_b` can be used independently. In other words, in `mainpackage`, there are references to `subpackage_a` and `subpackage_b`. In a nutshell, I want the user to be able to do `from myProject import subpackage_a` and start doing `subpackage_a.subfunction(args)` without calling `mainpackage`. I also want the user to use `from myProject import mainpackage` and start using `mainpackage.mainfucntion(args)`, where `mainpackage.mainfucntion` will call the functions in the `subpackage`s.

I learned about namespace packaging. However, I couldn't find anything on namespace packages that involve *dependencies*. I don't have to use namespace packaging if there's a better solution. Can I get some suggestions on what I should look for?

Comment: If `subpackage_a` and `subpackage_b` are independent why make them subpackages and not independent libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a name for your packages in the respective `setup.py` anyway and you can simply use those names when defining your dependencies. Here is a slightly simplified example with only one sub-package:

```
myProject
  sub/
    setup.py
    myProject/
      sub/
        __init__.py
  main/
    setup.py
    myProject/
      main/
        __init__.py
```

And you setups files should look like this:

`myProject/sub/setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name="my-project-sub",
    ...
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=["myProject.*"]),
)
```

`myProject/main/setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(
    name="my-project-main",
    ...
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=["myProject.*"]),
    install_requires=["my-project-sub"],
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it install the required sub-package on its own when installing the `main` package? I am getting a `ERROR: No matching distribution found for my-project-sub` when I try to install the main package first.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902365/4350939