# setup.py installing local packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

If I have a tree that looks like:

```
├── project
│   ├── package
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── setup.py
├── env
└── setup.py
```

Is there a way to include the nested setup.py in the install for the top setup.py? I want to avoid this:

```
pip install -e . ; cd project/package ; pip install -e .
```

Comment: Weird question.  Why do you have two `setup.py` in the first place?  It would be more typical to keep `project` and `package` in separate repos.

Comment: I want to be able to have packages/repos locally within the project

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668295/how-to-include-and-install-local-dependencies-in-setup-py-in-python

Answer (score 15):

The solution is to have two separate projects: a main project (usually an application) and a sub-project (usually a library). The main application has a dependency to the library.

## Tree structure and `setup.py`

The main project can have the following structure:

```
your_app/
|-- setup.py
ˋ-- src/
    ˋ-- your_app/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- module1.py
        ˋ-- ...
```

The `setup.py` of your application can be:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Your-App',
    version='0.1.0',
    install_requires=['Your-Library'],
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    url='https://github.com/your-name/your_app',
    license='MIT',
    author='Your NAME',
    author_email='your@email.com',
    description='Your main project'
)
```

You can notice that:

- The name of your application can be slightly different to the name of your package;
- This package has a dependency to "Your-Library", defined below;
- You can put your source in the `src` directory, but it is optional. A lot of project have none.

The sub-project can have the following structure:

```
your_library/
|-- setup.py
ˋ-- src/
    ˋ-- your_library/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- lib1.py
        ˋ-- ...
```

The `setup` of you library can be:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Your-Library',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    url='https://github.com/your-name/your_library',
    license='MIT',
    author='Your NAME',
    author_email='your@email.com',
    description='Your sub-project'
)
```

## Putting all things together

Create a virtualenv for your application and activate it

Go in the `your_library/` directory and run:

```
pip install -e .
```

Then, go in `your_app/` directory and run:

```
pip install -e .
```

You are now ready to code. Have fun!

See the [Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#structuring-your-project): “Structuring Your Project”.

Comment: They said that they wanted to avoid doing what your solution is asking to do.