# Setup.py install requires local package

Tags: python, setuptools

I am looking to install a package `my-package` using `setuptools`.  `my-package` has a local dependency, `utils`.  My file structure is as follows:

```
parent/
    my-package/
        my-package/
        setup.py
    utils/
        utils/
        setup.py
```

I am looking to install the local dependency using the following:

```
from setuptools import setup
import os

setup(
    name='my-package',
    version='1.0',
    packages=['my-package'],
    install_requires=[
        # location to your my-package project directory
        "file:\\" + os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()), 'utils#egg=utils-1.0')
    ]
)
```

Unfortunately this errors out with the following:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /path/to/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/my-package/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/my-package/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
         cwd: /home/my-package/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    error in my-package setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'://home/'"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668295/how-to-include-and-install-local-dependencies-in-setup-py-in-python) with no luck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure it works with `file://`, but if yes then it most likely belongs in a `dependency_links` item and in `install_requires` there should be only the project name of the dependency.

Comment: This works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668295/how-to-include-and-install-local-dependencies-in-setup-py-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dependency_links` is deprecated. This is a ugly hack, a very bad practice. I do not recommend you do this.

This hack is meant to be installed as `python setup.py install`, which is nowadays also deprecated. If you install with *pip*, then most likely this won't work.

In general, relative path dependencies are always a bad idea in Python packaging, I would recommend you solve it a different way.

With that said, something like this could work, or at least could have worked at some point in the past:

```
.
├── One
│   ├── one
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── setup.py
└── Two
    ├── setup.py
    └── two
        └── __init__.py
```

`One/setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools
import pathlib

TWO_PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.joinpath('Two')

setuptools.setup(
    name='One',
    version='1.2.3',
    packages=['one'],
    install_requires=['Two'],
    dependency_links=[
        'file://{}#egg=Two-1.2.3'.format(TWO_PATH),
    ],
)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. In my case, `Two` is inside `One`. Of course, I changed `pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.joinpath('Two')` to `pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent.joinpath('Two')`, and so the path should be correct, but it still returns me `ERROR: No matching distribution found for Two`. I'm using pip 20.3.3.

Comment: @nbro `dependency_links` is deprecated (probably already was at the time I wrote this). This whole thing is just a ugly hack, very bad practice. -- If you use _pip_ (in particular a recent one), then most likely this won't work because of build isolation, or maybe because of the intermediary wheel build step. -- This hack was meant to be installed as `python setup.py install`, I think. -- Relative path dependencies are not a good idea, I would recommend you solve it a different way.