# How to include local Python dependency in setup.cfg

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

A similar question has been asked before, but this time I am asking for the newer setuptools config file — `setup.cfg`.

Consider my use case, where I have a project with multiple Python packages that depends on each other. For simplicity let's say `mypkg1` depends on `mypkg2`:

```
mypkg1/
  mypkg1/
  setup.cfg
mypkg2/
  mypkg2/
  setup.cfg
```

How do I write the `setup.cfg` file for `mypkg1` such that it depends on a local copy of `mypkg2`?

```
[metadata]
name = mypkg1
version = 0.0.1

[options]
packages = find:
python_requires = >= 3.7
install_requires =
    ../mypkg2  # Does not work
```

The answer cannot be to distribute `mypkg2` to a package repository (e.g., PyPI) or some VCS release (e.g., GitHub Release) as these solutions makes the package external and no local.

---

Related Questions

- [How to include and install local dependencies in setup.py in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668295/how-to-include-and-install-local-dependencies-in-setup-py-in-python)

  This question is for `setup.py` which does not work for `setup.cfg`.
- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1951

  The discussion does not indicate any support for this nor any plans for this to be a feature.

Answer (score 2):

[Direct references](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#direct-references) still work. Looks like this:

```
install_requires =
    my_package @ file:///home/code/my_package
```

Note the triple-slash in file:/// - the first two are the usual schema://, the third one is what separates the empty <host> (defaults to localhost) from the path.

Comment: Is there any way to this dynamically?. I mean something like  my_package @ file:///{PATH_to_PACKAGE}