# How to build Python project including dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a few projects, all containing *`setup.py`* and *`requirements.txt`*. Is it possible to package a whole project in one single file including all requirements compiled and ready to install?

What I have tried:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Builds a *`.whl`* file and puts it in the *`dist`* directory. The wheel does not contain any dependencies.

```
pip wheel -r requirements.txt -w wheelhouse
```

Builds wheels for every single requirement and puts it in the *`wheelhouse`* directory. Includes nicely compiled code for *`numpy`* for example (I know I have to build this on every platform I want it to run later on, that's fine).

**Seems I am just missing the last piece of the puzzle.**

Comment: That's not how Python packaging works: you don't bundle every dependency into one file, but have to install each one separately.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38642658/95735

Comment: Related: [Build a wheel/egg and all dependencies for a python project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26059111/95735)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at tools like [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/) or [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) if you absolutely want one single file containing everything. Pip itself cannot do what you want.