# Build "fat eggs"

Tags: python, egg

I'd like to distribute my python project in a single egg, and be able to deploy it without having to pull its dependencies using pip. Something like:

```
PYTHONPATH=my_egg.egg python -m my_egg
```

where my egg has many dependencies, and the current python environment is clean. From what I've heard, python eggs are similar to java jars, so is there some analogous concept in python for *fat* java jars?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059111/build-a-wheel-egg-and-all-dependencies-for-a-python-project

Comment: It is also possible to use anaconda environments (`conda env`). It has advantage over wheel that it reliefs the pain of providing or compiling native dependencies, like `blas` and `lapack` for `numpy`.