# How can I create a Python executable program that doesn't force the user to actually download Python libraries and that stuff in order to be executed?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, operating-system, software-design

Let's say that I already built a program that essentially takes some images from an user's path and make new ones using the following libraries/modules:

```
os itertools pandas PIL
```

What I need now is to make that program become an executable file that can be actually executed **without having to have installed the Python environment and the libraries used in the code**, because the user would not know how to code, and would not likely matter how the code works.

The program would run on **Windows OS (PC)** only , and would use the `cmd.exe` as the interpreter and medium for user inputs and results display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059111/build-a-wheel-egg-and-all-dependencies-for-a-python-project)
You can use wheel, and ship whole environment.

@Vincent Caeles:
"*@rh979 a wheel is not meant to have all dependencies. Subsequently you could do `pip install path/to/wheel.whl --target /path/to/some/folder` and zip the contents of the 'folder' to have all your dependencies in the zip archive and ship that to the environment where you want to run your code.*
"

Another options is `pyinstaller` library, according to documentation it should do what you need.

Comment: Do you know if ```pyinstaller``` does the same?

Comment: Good point according to documentation seems to be the solution. But no personal exp with this lib.

Comment: All right, I think I got what is needed, anyway I give you the check ✓